# Recovering mail in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

After importing an old backup, can I still recover more recent emails?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open again the file (ie: Outlook. pst ) It should take the new ones.

Not import, but open in an special way: Go to File menu, Open, Outlook Data File. You should have just copied the pst file from the folder, not "exported" from your other Outlook.